# Delete all the pages on mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

I am trying to delete all the pages, created on my mediawiki.

I tried "Special:Nuke" , and these scripts:

```
php maintenance/nukeNS.php --delete --all

php deleteArchivedRevisions.php --delete

php purgeList.php --purge --all

php nukeNS.php --ns=1 --all --delete
```

However, I can still see pages. Looks like these scripts does nothing.

Comment: Are you certain it isn't cached?

Comment: @Steve, I am not. However I tried invalidate the cache as described in manual.

Answer (score 2):

Documentation is your friend.

- [purgeList.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:PurgeList.php):

  > purgeList.php file is a maintenance script to send purge requests for listed pages to squids.
- [deleteArchivedRevisions.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:DeleteArchivedRevisions.php):

  > deleteArchivedRevisions.php file is a maintenance script to delete all the archived (hidden from public view) revisions, by clearing out the archive table. These revisions will no longer be restorable. Deleted pages and archived revisions to a given page are permanently deleted, but the complete history of existing pages will remain.
- [nukeNS.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:NukeNS.php):

  > nukeNS.php file is a maintenance script to remove all pages with only one revision (by default) from the MediaWiki namespace, without flooding recent changes, deletion logs, etc. It has originally been added to remove the content of unchanged interface texts from the MediaWiki namespace, but it can be used to basically delete all pages from any namespace.

So nukeNS.php is the one you want (possibly followed up by deleteArchivedRevisions.php if you want the content completely removed from the database). Probably most of your pages are in namespace 0.

Comment: It looks like they tried all those though, and nothing worked.

Comment: Probably there wasn't anything in NS 1 (Talk).

Comment: What NS do they need to use, or how do they figure it out? (nevermind, I see you have that in your last paragraph)

Comment: You badly read my question! I tried all this stuff!